# I add onClickListener in my custom view in ViewPager, but ViewPager cant't scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

[picture](http://test.longdw.com/pic.png) 
Look at the picture, left one is my custom view composed by many textviews, right one is picture, when I add onClickListener to textview, I cant't scroll viewPager, please tell me how can I solve this problem, thank you very much!!!

this is my [demo](http://test.longdw.com/TestLabel.zip)

Comment: on which api you are testing . because on my device api 4.3 you code is working..

Comment: my api is 4.3 also, my code is working, but can't scroll from left to right,I find the answer to this problem, because of the textview setGravity(center) and setSingle(true) at the same time, this is bug.